# no matching function for call to LiquidCrystal::setCursor(int)

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, lcd

So, i was trying to make the cursor move on an lcd with a joystick but,

I type this:

```
int iniCursorX=6;
int iniCursorY=2;
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> //lcd

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2); //setting up lcd

// Arduino pin numbers
const int SW_pin = 6; // digital pin connected to switch output
const int X_pin = 0; // analog pin connected to X output
int Y_pin = 1; // analog pin connected to Y output

void setup() {
pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
lcd.print("Hello!");
analogWrite(Y_pin, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
lcd.setCursor(iniCursorX,iniCursorY);
lcd.cursor();
delay(200);
lcd.noCursor();
delay(200);

if(Y_pin=0, iniCursorX >= 2) {
int j=iniCursorX; 
lcd.setCursor(j-1);



}
}
```

Then I Get this:
    no matching function for call to LiquidCrystal::setCursor(int)

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of your code you have:

```
lcd.setCursor(j-1);
```

but [lcd.setCursor](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystalSetCursor) takes two arguments.
Change it to something like `lcd.setCursor(0, j-1);` or anything you need.

Comment: Thanks Bro, helped

Comment: @AlexTheKid Great! Don't forget to mark this post as an answer.